# AngularJS loading new page using ng-include and templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, angularjs-templates

I have a form with some contents and some buttons. What I want to do is by clicking a button, hide the original contents of the form and load some new contents. Now I have done the hiding part using ng-show . But i'm stuck at loading new contents using ng include. I have included the contents that I want to show inside script tags and tried to load on button click.

This is what I have done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div class="container">

    <form role="form" id="info_form" name="info_form" ng-controller="infoCtrl" ng-app="app"  novalidate>

        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                Fill your medical information
                <!--<small>Optional description</small>-->
            </h1>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="box">

                <div class="box-body" ng-show="table_remove" >
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">

                            <div style="margin-top: 15px;width: 100%;">
                                <!--first block-->
                                <div style="float: left;width: 33%;height: 100%">

                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="info_ques_text">Maximum Heart Rate</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input class='input' type="number" name="Heart" id="Heart" class="form-control"  ng-model="data.heart_rate" placeholder="Enter Value" required><br>
                                            <span class="error_msg" ng-show="submitted && info_form.Heart.$error.required">Value cannot be blank</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <!--third block-->

                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="info_ques_text">How Long Do You Work Per Day?</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <select class='input' name="Work" id="Work" ng-model="data.work" ng-selected="" required>
                                                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Option</option>
                                                <option value="0">4-5 Hours</option>
                                                <option value="1">5-6 Hours</option>
                                                <option value="2">6-7 Hours</option>
                                                <option value="3">More than 7 Hours</option>
                                            </select><br>
                                            <span class="error_msg" ng-show="submitted && info_form.Work.$error.required">Value cannot be blank</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer" ng-show="table_remove">
        <button href="" type="submit" ng-click="submitted = true; train(data);" class="btn btn-primary">Train data</button>
        <button href="" type="submit" ng-click="submitted = true; submit(data); template = 'predictview'" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{{url()}}/admin/organizations/view">Cancel</a>
                </div>

            </div>

<ng-include src="template"></ng-include>

            <script type="text/ng-template" id="predictview">

                        <div class="container" ng-controller="questionEditCtrl" >

                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name='quizAdd' ng-submit="submit(data2)">

                         <a> New page </a>
                      </form>
                        </div>
            </script>

</section><!-- /.content -->
    </form>

</div>
</html>
```

Comment: i am facing the same problem ,.

Comment: paste the answer if you have resolved this issue .,